# Best way to import a Python list into an HTML table?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I wrote a script that scrapes various things from around the web and stores them in a python list and have a few questions about the best way to get it into a HTML table to display on a web page.

1. First off should my data be in a list? It will at most be a 25 by 9 list.
2. I’m assuming I should write the list to a file for the web site to import? Is a text file preferred or something like a CSV, XML file?
3. Whats the standard way to import a file into a table? In my quick look around the web I didn’t see an obvious answer (Major web design beginner). Is Javascript this best thing to use? Or can python write out something that can easily be read by HTML?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- store everything in a database eg:  sqlite,mysql,mongodb,redis ...

  - then query the db every time you want to display the data.
    this is good for changing it later from multiple sources.
- store everything in a "flat file": sqlite,xml,json,msgpack

  - again, open and read the file whenever you want to use the data.
  - or read it in completly on startup
  - simple and often fast enough.
- generate a html file from your list with a template engine eg jinja, save it as html file.

  - good for simple hosters

There are some good python webframeworks out there some i used:

> Flask, Bottle, Django, Twisted, Tornado

They all more or less output html.

- Feel free to use HTML5/DHTML/Java Script.
  You could use a webframework to create/use an "api" on the backend, which serves json or xml.
  Then your java script callback will display it on your site.

Comment: Thanks. I think Flask and Jinja will more than suit my needs!

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to create an HTML table is to loop through your list and print out the rows.

```
print '<table><tr><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th>...</tr>'
for row in my_list:
    print '<tr>'
    for col in row:
        print '<td>%s</td>' % col
    print '</tr>'
print '</table>'
```

Adjust the code as needed for your particular table.